# Optimized Averaging of Large Array?

Tags: python, average

So i have a .wav file. from this i got the data:
as expected from a sound file it is in stereo so the data looks like

### List 1 (Original List)

> [ [1,2],
>     [2,3],
>     [4,9],
>     [1,5],
>     [1,7],
>     ....]

Note: I just made up those numbers, however the point is it's a nested list.
The problem here is I'm doing FFT on that and as such want to only use the average of the two channels so i want:

### List 2 (Averaged)

> [ 
>   [1.5],
>   [2.5],
>   [6.5],
>   [3],
>   [4],
>   ....
>   ]

so for that I did:

```
averaged_array =  [sum(x)/len(x) for x in original_list]
```

I assume len(x) is a constant time operation even though it will always be 2.

The problem here is that the length of the original list is >900,000 I believe. On my home computer I can average it in ~46 seconds. At the computer I have to use for the presentation it takes ~121 seconds. This is a sizeable increase and it frankly is bad to have to wait around while it runs. Is there anyway I can optimize this so the time it takes it reduced?

Note: I believe this is a double core computer so I cannot run this in parallel (I think?). 
It is possible for me to ssh into a server (with a few i7's running on it) which I've been given permission to use.. Would it be better if I somehow ssh'ed and did the calculations there? The original computer I'm using I believe is ~2 ghz but is an old dell model relative (the series from a few years ago). Additionally, McAfee and another process eat up ~50% of the processing as well and I have no rights to kill these.

If I do that:

- How would I do the calculations on this remote computer via SSH? (I'm using python 2.7 and would really prefer not to install any external libraries as this is not my computer but an organization computer)
- Would I be able to do the calculations in a sort of "order"? I thought that when doing things in parallel, you could not maintain order as it would be done as soon as a core is open to compute it. By order I mean: I want the list to maintain the average at the same index of the original list. 
  Ex. [ [1,2], [3,4]] should give [ [2.5], [3.5]] not [ [3.5], [2.5]]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this kind of tasks, you really want to use the de facto standard [NumPy](http://numpy.org/) module. This module handles large arrays in an efficient way (it even does FFT for you, if this is what you need).

Here is how you can do your average:

```
>>> a = numpy.array([[1,2], [2,3], [4,9], [1,5], [1,7]])
>>> numpy.average(a, axis=-1)
array([ 1.5,  2.5,  6.5,  3. ,  4. ])
```

Performing the average on an array of 1 million pairs takes only 22 ms on my machine.

The FFT can then be done with the `numpy.fft` module.

Comment: hmm i'm already using the numpy.fft module :D
i'll try this, thanks! just wondering, is there anyway to keep this with nested lists ex. [[1,2],[3,4]] as I believe I'm already using that in the rest of the program

Comment: @user997301: Suck it up and make the rest of your script compatible with numpy. You'll enjoy the benefits in the long run. Also, you should update your name.

Comment: @user997301: NumPy will gladly accept nested lists instead of NumPy arrays. However, the most time- and memory-efficient approach for your kind of task is to not manipulate Python lists at all, but to use NumPy arrays from the beginning on.

Comment: ok then! the irony is I think i'm using numpy arrays for everything else and actually doing some converting xD

Comment: I am doing all FFT's in numpy :D and i'm running one every second on 44,000 samples and it needs to finish within a second, so i can testify to it's efficiency :D

Comment: @EOL suggested you use NumPy. If you do that, then you shouldn't use the Python native module to import the wave file; instead, use the SciPy function, `scipy.io.wavfile.read()`.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/io.html

It will be a lot faster.

Comment: actually i tried that a few times but:
1) it returns a nice array....of i have no clue what datatype. I tried to use struct unpack on it but had no luck.. (i want to be able to first get it in nice ints, then put it back in whatever datatype it came from so that i can output it via pymedia).
2) it has almost no documentation. at least _descriptive_ documentation and frankly I see almost no examples

Comment: Numpy had the average in 3 second compared to 120 via a list comprehension in Python. The speed is awesome :)